# css background-position change on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I have this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/zn09vjbv/2/

I am trying to get it so that

```
nth-child(1) :hover h2 span {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
```

that code doesn't work below is the snippet from the css in the jfiddle

```
li:hover .browser * {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;
    transition:opacity 1500ms ease-out;

}


#privateinfo h2 span {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
#privateinfo :hover h2 span {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
#healthcare h2 span {
  background-position: -100px 0;
}
#healthcare:hover h2 span {
  background-position: -100px -100px;
}
#smallorgs h2 span {
  background-position: -200px 0;
}
#smallorgs:hover h2 span {
  background-position: -200px -100px;

}
#associations h2 span {
  background-position: -300px 0;
}
#associations:hover h2 span {
  background-position: -300px -100px;
}
#studentinfo h2 span {
  background-position: -400px 0;
}
#studentinfo:hover h2 span {
  background-position: -400px -100px;
}
```

the li:hover . browser bit works great but I also want it so that if each `<li>` is hovered it also enacts the background position for the relevant div...... Currently the hover for h2 span only works if you enter its are and i want it to change position if you enter the relevant li ...... any ideas ?

Cheers,
Greg.

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Also, if it's important to you, `background-position` [is not supported in IE8 and under](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets)

Comment: ah right well , the css above allow h2 span position of the specific div to change ... this is great but instead of the hover over h2span i want it to be over the li like the main bit above at the top

Comment: ...also IE 8 only refers to 1%/ of users :op

Comment: I don't think `background-position` is the property you are looking for. The spans don't have any backgrounds to position...do they?

Comment: yes i am using an image that contains the rollover images.... it is contained in the H2 span css that refers to browser-bg .... you dont get to see it on the jsfiddle though as i couldnt figure out how to upload it ... i am quite sure it is simple css changes but very confused

Comment: in essence why is it that nth-child(1) :hover h2 span {
  background-position: 0 -100px; doesn't work referring to the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably a bit confusing my side but in the end i needed to align the ref point of background position to nth child istead of the div currently used soooo...

```
li:nth-child(1) h2 span {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
li:nth-child(1):hover h2 span {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

that worked a treat ! fair play to me